# Faster prime-generating algorithm than sieving?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The fastest ways of generating primes is through any of the sieving algorithms, where you cross out multiples of the already known primes, starting with the prime 2, until you find a lowest number that is not a multiple of any of the already known primes, and then you add that prime and cross out multiples of that prime, and so on. But could there be a faster way of generating primes that does not involve sieving?

I'm talking about generating all primes from 2 to some n.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Are you talking about generating single primes, all primes from 2 to some $n$, all (or some) primes in a given range, etc?

Comment: Sieving is much faster than checking every number individually , if you want the primes from $2$ to some $n$. In this case, there is nothing better. If you want to have the primes within a small range of huge numbers, then the best you can do is to sieve and test the remaining candidates.

Answer (score 5):

In theory the Sieve of Atkin, which is using a quadratic form for sieving, is the fastest known algorithm.

In practice, however, the implementation of this sieve is such that it is not worth it and, because of technicalities with added calculations that you need to do, it turns out practically not faster than Eratosthenes even for extremely large primes.
Eratosthenes is such that you can start from any place and wind it up with, basically, as many small primes as you like from the library with always the same most trivial operation one could imagine and then continue.

So theoretically and some careful implementations of Sieve of Atkin do outperform Eratosthenes, but you need some hardware architecture support, and, look, we are talking about $\ln(\ln(n))$ difference (to compare $\ln(\ln(10^{10000})) \approx 10$), so this means that if you can speed up addition or add some detail to Eratosthenes that will exclude some portion of primes etc. that might count more than that Atkin general factor that should have reduced the speed couple of times - in theory.

Practically, Eratosthenes sieve is fast enough and simple enough to be generally used. Theoretically at the moment, there are faster algorithms that are more complicated to implement to truly obtain still slight theoretical advantage.

Anyway, you will not get far from some sort of sieving in the end that is an Eratosthenes cousin. And if you do need sieving, there is no practical reason not to use Eratosthenes. Notice that a trivial optimization, for example that all numbers not yet flagged from $n$ to $(n+1)^2$ are all primes, allow you to read a lot of primes in bulks.

If we mark $p_s$ the last prime that we have just used for sieving (i.e. to mark all numbers divisible by $p_s$) and $p_d$ the newly just discovered next prime that is not used for sieving yet then here is the theorem:

*Theorem*

All not yet marked numbers during the sieving $k$,  $p_{{n-1},s} < k <p_{n,d}^2$ are all primes.

*Proof:*

If $k$,  $p_{{n-1},s} < k <p_{n,d}^2$, is not flagged yet then its factorization must contain other primes all greater than $p_{{n-1},s}$. So the smallest factor it can have and remain unmarked is $p_{n}$. Any other prime content would mark this number.

But $\prod\limits_{m=2}^{M} d_m \geq p_{n}^2$, since each $d_m \geq p_n$ which means that first such composite not yet flagged number must be outside the interval $p_{{n-1},s} < k <p_{n,d}^2$. So all numbers that are not marked yet as divisible by some other number during the sieving within  $p_{{n-1},s} < k <p_{n,d}^2$ are primes.

Notice that since you have to scan all numbers to collect primes, there is no need to do multiplication of $p_{n}^2$ you just read $p_{n}$ length segments $p_{n}$ times. (Here it is your upper limit that decides how to proceed, so you already know recursively what to do: say you want primes up to $65536=2^{16}$, you need primes up to $256=2^{8}$, for which you need primes up to $16=2^{4}$, for which you need primes up to $4=2^{2}$, and the games can begin.)

This means that you sieve $2,3,5$ and get all prime numbers up to $49$, or $2,3,5,7,11,13,17$ all up to $361$ without any further sieving. Primes up to $1000$ give first million primes. This is not that bad for such a simple algorithm. Being able to separate sieving from extraction allows parallelization, using more hardware to get faster result. This is why the theoretical difference between Eratosthenes and Atkin counts little.

Comment: In fact you know all values up to at least $n^3$ are either primes or semiprimes. After sieving to $n$

Comment: The $slowest$ algorithm is probably by Ghandi's Formula. Let $p$ be an odd prime and let $Q$ be the product of all the primes less than $p$. Let $S=-1/2+\sum_{n|Q}\frac {\mu(n)}{2^n-1}$ where $\mu$ is the Mobius function. Then $1<2^pS<2.$ That is, $p$ is the least $m\in \Bbb N$ such that $1<2^mS. $ For example, to find the least prime $p>200$ we first need to know all $45$ primes less than $200$, and then the expression for $S$ has $2^{45}+1$ terms in it.

Comment: Well, theoretically the fastest one would be on $n$-bit decimal machine ($n \gg 1$) that is able to divide. Then it is all $\bigoplus\limits_{k>1} \frac1{2^k(2^k-1)}$ where $\bigoplus$ is logical OR. Then primes are all $0$'s after first decimal place. Complexity $O(n)$ since division and OR are just two 1-cycle operations on that machine. We should build such hardware just for primes. It is worth having it.

Comment: Correct ! Erathosthenes is definitely good enough. The main problem is anyway to store the primes. For practical purposes, we do not need such a list anyway since numbers upto $100$ decimal digits can be checked for primality (including a primality proof) within less than a second.

Comment: Peter, sieving gets really slow when you want to generate big primes like those greater than 10^9.

Comment: In order to examine prime gaps the longest list of primes ever produced (but not stored) is up to around $10^{18}$ basically all primes gaps up to $2^{64} = 18446744073709551616$ are now examined. Even beyond that it is still Eratosthenes "After some preliminary tests, we found that the Sieve of Eratosthenes, SE, from the year 250 BC was the fastest for finding prime numbers and it could also be made space efficient". The fact that it took couple of years... yes it is slow at those heights, but that is why any optimization is extremely important.

Comment: And not to forget: Why do we calculate primes? Can't we just store them? In order to store all $64$-bit long primes we would need $3.300.000$ Tb of space, which you can reduce to $500.000$ Tb using compression. But that means replacing broken disks constantly and recalculating broken segments again and again. Such warehouse would consume a lot of energy and would be very slow to access. So even after $250$BC+$2021$AC we have nothing better. Old philosophers had no practical reason to investigate anything. We do. So they excelled beyond us in some sense.

Answer (score 0):

To fully understand why Eratosthenes, with additional optimizations that are oriented to use efficiently memory and processing powers of currently dominant computer architecture, will not be easily surpassed, imagine that we want to enlist all primes up to the largest currently known prime:

$$2^{77,232,917}-1$$

Eratosthenes has $n\ln(\ln(n))$ where the factor $\ln(\ln(2^{77,232,917}-1)) \approx 18$ only $18$ times linear! Take $18$ computers, distribute all that calculation and there you go.

If you say, no, no I will put an effort and try to enlist only primes you would still need

$$\frac{2^{77,232,917}-1}{\ln(2^{77,232,917}-1)}$$

locations. But the factor $\ln(2^{77,232,917}-1)$ is what $2^{25}$ around $10.000.000$ which is, if you ever envision such an algorithm, nothing in comparison to $2^{77,232,917}-1$ which is about $10$ over that number.

For this reason we are talking about using more efficient memory structures, reducing the number of flagging through various properties of primes, distribution processing and all that in order to reduce a potential couple of years to a couple of hours. But you see, if it is all about having more money to buy a better equipment, we tend to stay with a somewhat simpler solution because we do not want to start a program that has a potential bug discovered only too late not to abandone everything. Only in case it is some sort of one-time-never-to-return-sending-a-rocket-to-Mars, we try to optimize everything to the last atom.

Theoretically, there are better methods for finding primes, guessing primes, factorization and all that, but to enlist all primes Eratosthenes will need another kind of math to be bitten. The current one is not breaking a linear barrier by much.

Notice however that future progress might lead to some sort of inherited parallelization (quantum computers) that will reduce it all to less than a linear factor, at least in execution. But even with that it will be still good old Eratosthenes just revamped.

Another possibility is that we will be able to find a pattern into prime distribution and, sort of, first list where all primes could be $n\ln(n)$ and then deal with the error term reducing it bellow $1$ (we are nowhere near such a thing). Even this will not beat Eratosthenes by much since just to calculate the probable position of a prime number requires at least calculating it all for each prime. Currently everything points that primes after $1.000.000^{th}$ are behaving as randomly drunken walk would around the average well-known distribution. But... Riemann zeta zeros might reveal some surprise in a way that cannot be predicted.

So far, Greeks are as good as ever.